# Hello, I need the picture translated. Can someone help?

Tags: translation, character-identification

This picture is Chinese text on a pavilion in my city. I'm very curious to know what it means since there is little external information on it. [image: The image of Chinese characters]

Comment: 常熟亭 (Always Familiar  Pavilion )  2005 AD 張浩元 (Zhang Haoyuan )書(written by)

Answer (score 1):

This is a plaque, the words on it describe the information is a building for people to rest。
常熟亭（Chang Shu Ting) is name of the plaque.
公元二00五年（Gong Yuan er ling ling wu nian）Is the construction date。
张浩元書（Zhang Hao Yuan Shu)This plaque written by a person named Zhang Haoyuan